# Creating a pair of its order, value in a list in python

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's assume that we have a following list:

```
[3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
```

(this is just an example, could be any list containing real numbers of arbitrary length)

if we sort it, we get

```
[-1, 2, 3, 5, 100]
```

meaning -1 is the smallest, 2 is 2nd smallest, 3 is 3rd smallest, 5 is 4th smallest, 100 is the largest, so if -1 is 1st order statistic, 2 is 2nd order statistic, 3 is 3rd order statistic, 5 is 4th order statistic, 100 is 5th order statistic. Now, going back to the original list, I would want to change the original list

```
[3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
```

to

```
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```

a list of pair of (value, its order)

Is there a python in-built library function that does it? or do we have to build a manual function for this?

Comment: In my opinion, you have to build manual function for this.
Correct me if you find any library/built-in function for doing this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: crpytic one-liners are silly but fun: `list(zip(x, map(dict(map(reversed, enumerate(sorted(x),1))).__getitem__,x)))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Cute, but it doesn't handle dupes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
s = [3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
new_s = sorted(s)
final_s = [(i, new_s.index(i)+1) for i in s]
```

Output:

```
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```

If `s` is non unique:

```
s = [3, 3, 3, 2, 100, -1, 100, 5]
new_s = sorted(s)
final_s = [(a, [i for i, b in enumerate(new_s) if b == a]) for a in s]
last_s = [(a, list(map(lambda x:x+1, b)) if len(b) > 1 else b[0]) for a, b in final_s]
```

Output:

```
[(3, [3, 4, 5]), (3, [3, 4, 5]), (3, [3, 4, 5]), (2, 1), (100, [7, 8]), (-1, 0), (100, [7, 8]), (5, 5)]
```

Comment: This might have a problem if items in `s` are not unique.

Comment: @Galen good point. I added a solution to account for that. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: The output of your 2nd version does not look correct. Why are there lists inside the tuples?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way that avoids using `.index`. There are two problems with the `.index` method. Firstly, it's relatively slow, because it has to perform a linear scan over the list items until it finds a matching item. Secondly, it always stops when it finds the first matching item, so using it for this task is problematic if there are duplicate items in the original list. One way around this problem is to use `enumerate` twice.

This is a slightly complex operation, so I'll do it in stages.

```
a = [3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
print(a)

b = sorted((u, i) for i, u in enumerate(a))
print(b)

c = sorted((i, u, j) for j, (u, i) in enumerate(b, 1))
print(c)

d = [u[1:] for u in c]
print(d)
```

**output**

```
[3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
[(-1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (5, 4), (100, 3)]
[(0, 3, 3), (1, -1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 100, 5), (4, 5, 4)]
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```

It's *possible* to combine those 3 stages into a single statement, but the result is an almost unreadable monstrosity. ;)

```
d = [u[1:] for u in sorted((i, u, j) for j, (u, i) in
    enumerate(sorted((u, i) for i, u in enumerate(a)), 1))]
```

FWIW, this technique is a variant of the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

---

Here's a test with a list that contains a duplicate item that compares my algorithm with the algorithm that uses `.index`.

```
a = [3, -1, 2, 100, -1, 5]
print(a)

lst = a
sorted_list = [(e, i+1) for i,e in enumerate(sorted(lst))]
result = sorted(sorted_list, key = lambda x : lst.index(x[0]))
print(result)

b = sorted((u, i) for i, u in enumerate(a))
c = sorted((i, u, j) for j, (u, i) in enumerate(b, 1))
d = [u[1:] for u in c]
print(d)
```

**output**

```
[3, -1, 2, 100, -1, 5]
[(3, 4), (-1, 1), (-1, 2), (2, 3), (100, 6), (5, 5)]
[(3, 4), (-1, 1), (2, 3), (100, 6), (-1, 2), (5, 5)]
```

As you can see, my version puts the second `-1` in its correct place.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try something like this:

```
>>> lst = [3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
>>> sorted_list = [(e, i+1) for i,e in enumerate(sorted(lst))]
>>> print(sorted_list)
[(-1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (5, 4), (100, 5)]
>>> result = sorted(sorted_list, key = lambda x : lst.index(x[0]))
>>> print(result)
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```

If you have duplicates in your list, you need to change your approach. One way is to group similar values in a dictionary by `(number, [counts])`, and `pop()` them off one at a time once you read the original values from `lst`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [3, -1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 100, 5]

sorted_list = [(e, i+1) for i,e in enumerate(sorted(lst))]

d = defaultdict(list)
for number, count in sorted_list:
    d[number].append(count)

result = [(number, d[number].pop(0)) for number in lst]

print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
[(3, 4), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 5), (5, 6), (2, 3), (100, 8), (5, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in just two simple steps let's explore step by step:

> first step:

track the sorted list index and value so for this we can use dict:

```
track={}
data_1=[3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
for i,j in enumerate(sorted(data_1),1):
    track[j]=i
```

which will give :

```
{2: 2, 3: 3, 100: 5, 5: 4, -1: 1}
```

> Second step

just iterate over original data and fetch the key of that item from track dict :

```
print([(item,track.get(item)) for item in data_1])
```

output:

```
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Comment: Neat, but it doesn't cope with duplicate items in `data_1`.

Answer (score 1):

One liner which does not use index and handles duplicates.

```
>>> s = [3, -1, 2, 100, 5]
>>> list((x[1][1], x[0]) for x in sorted(enumerate(sorted(enumerate(s), key=lambda x: x[1]), 1), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
[(3, 3), (-1, 1), (2, 2), (100, 5), (5, 4)]
```